# Jupyter Notebook) Is it possible to create a new dataset by adding rows that correspond to a common column in a dataset?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dataset

[image]

Hello. I want to append all data from the same date to the above data set and merge them into one.
And I want to create a dataset of sum values ​​by date. How are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['date'])[column_name_that.sum()
```